# Django: Most Efficient Way To Filter A Queryset Repeatedly

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model that looks something like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    type = models.CharField()
    tags = models.models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
```

In order to render a given view, I have a view that presents a list of Items based on type.  So in my view, there's a query like:

```
items = Item.objects.filter(type='type_a')
```

So that's easy and straight forward.  Now I have an additional requirement for the view.  In order to fulfill that requirement, I need to build a dictionary that relates Tags to Items.  So the output i am looking for would be something like:

```
{
    'tag1': [item1, item2, item5],
    'tag2': [item1, item4],
    'tag3': [item3, item5]
}
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this?  Is there any way to do this without going to the database with a new query for each tag?

Answer (score 3):

You can check [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) it might help you:

> This has a similar purpose to `select_related`, in that both are designed to stop the deluge of database queries that is caused by accessing related objects, but the strategy is quite different... `prefetch_related`, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done using select_related...

So in the end you will either do multiple queries or use `prefetch_related` and it will do some Python joins on the objects.

Answer (score 2):

You might do something like this:

```
# This should require two database queries, one for the items 
# and one for all the associated tags.
items = Item.objects.filter(type='type_a').prefetch_related('tags')

# Now massage the data into your desired data structure.
from collections import defaultdict
tag_dict = defaultdict(list)
for item in items:
    # Thanks to prefetch_related this will not hit the database.
    for tag in item.tags.all():
        tag_dict[tag].append(item)
```